# Has anyone analyzed the survival rate of new SO users based on quality of first question(s)?

Tags: discussion, new-users, statistics

A common way to look at the quality of an online community is by the survival rate of new members. Basically `S(t)` where `S` is the % of people surviving after time `t`. It can also be based on events rather than time such as number of visits, or number of questions asked.

What I'm curious about is how populations of new users on SO survive depending on the ratings of their first question. I read recently that those whose first questions are downvoted have a low survival rate but I don't recall actual numbers or a statistical model. I do not yet have enough rep on SO to run the analysis myself afaik.

Comment: You mean you don't have enough rep to go to SEDE and run the query? That's bizarre.

Comment: I may have the rep and not know it, I've never seen an alert saying I now have access. How much does one need?

Comment: Don't really know; never really tried when I was low rep (low as in < 100).  Give it a go and see how far you get.

Comment: I don't think there's a lower limit. For some reason, I've edited queries as Anonymous and was able to run them after doing a CAPCHA.

Comment: It's difficult to differentiate new users from new accounts....  SO has a relatively high churn because it actually has some quality standards, so the incompetents, deadbeats, vamps and other SO abusers tend to open an account per question.

Comment: @Makoto: you were right, I had access and didn't know it. Now seeing what I can find on my own.

Comment: There is no reputation limit for SEDE - even anonymous people can use it.

Comment: @Undo SEDE lies too much for stats like asked for in this question because it doesn't have data on deleted users and has very limited data on deleted questions (that said I recall such stats posted a while ago by Shog or by Tim Post who have access to dev data)

Comment: @MartinJames I suspect that that issue will make any answer to this question an approximation at best or highly suspect at the very least. Still could be worth seeing it from the angle of "account survival" instead of actual "user" survival.

Comment: Lack of data on deleted users will indeed make survival analysis difficult. I'll only be able to look at users who just stopped participating.

Comment: It seems to me that this may not be a particularly good measure of the quality of this specific online community, with such a large class of users who join just to get a question answered one time without ever intending to really be a part of the community.

Comment: When you say "first question", do you mean "first post"? I think not all users ask questions.

Comment: I think this might be a question wrongly asked.  It's not a question of whether a user being downvoted makes them go away, because it is nigh impossible to tell if a given user asked a poor question because he was lazy; or if he was temporarily ignorant of the quality expectations of SO; or if he simply got an ill-deserved downvote.  There would need to be some more fine-grained human classification of those questions to make that measure.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler later I will come back and ask if anyone has ever built a machine classifier that can predict the quality score of a question...

Comment: I know that I hate asking questions on Stack Overflow and tend to spend hours searching online and poring over old, often outdated answers on SO, even when someone could and would gladly and quickly answer my question.

Comment: @Mallory-Erik: *Good*! That's the correct thing to do. Stack Overflow is not and should not become a replacement for _thought_ and _research_ and _studying_. You have opted not to take the easy way out and rely on those unscrupulous hoodlums on SO who enable laziness. Keep it up!

Comment: @MichelFloyd: This Kaggle competition is pretty close: https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow - you could probably take one of the top models and adjust it to predict some quality metric instead of closure.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[This has been queried before by Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216683/what-happens-to-new-users), but I pulled some current numbers for the past year of new users; new users being users who created an account in the last year.

### Overall New Users

Over the past year, there were **480155** new users who asked at least one question, of those questions:

```
+-------------------------------+--------+
|        Question Stats         | Total  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Closed                        |  79317 |
| Deleted                       | 124892 |
| Score < 0                     | 150105 |
| Score > 0                     | 112641 |
| At least 1 Answer on Question | 266698 |
+-------------------------------+--------+
```

**30274** users hit a question or answer block at some point in the past year.

Of the new users, **220459** users went on to post again, either questions or answers:

```
+------------------------+--------+
|                        | Total  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Asked Another Question | 180880 |
| Answered               | 102075 |
| Post Scored > 0        |  90468 |
| Post Scored < 0        | 101442 |
+------------------------+--------+
```

I wanted to know how many of these users who are no longer active. This is the breakdown of how many users who haven't logged into the site in X many days:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Days Since Active | Total Users |
+-------------------+-------------+
| < 7               |      129400 |
| 7 - 30            |       60126 |
| 30 - 60           |       45026 |
| 60 - 90           |       34463 |
| 90 - 120          |       26310 |
| 120 - 180         |       66044 |
| 180+              |      118786 |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

### Users with First Question Closed

**79317** users had their first question closed, of these questions:

```
+-------------------------------+--------+
|        Question Stats         | Total  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Deleted                       | 57987  |
| Score < 0                     | 55926  |
| Score > 0                     | 3375   |
| At least 1 Answer on Question | 28402  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
```

**9689** users hit a question or answer block at some point.  **32924** users went on to ask another question or post an answer:

```
+------------------------+--------+
|                        | Users  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Asked Another Question | 29324  |
| Answered               | 11159  |
| Post Scored > 0        | 10969  |
| Post Scored < 0        | 19506  |
+------------------------+--------+
```

The numbers of the users who have recently logged into the site:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Days Since Active | Total Users |
+-------------------+-------------+
| < 7               |      18339  |
| 7 - 30            |      10895  |
| 30 - 60           |       8110  |
| 60 - 90           |       6462  |
| 90 - 120          |       5132  |
| 120 - 180         |      11257  |
| 180+              |      19122  |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

### Users with First Question Deleted

**124892** users who had their first question deleted.

```
+-------------------------------+--------+
|        Question Stats         | Total  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Closed                        | 57987  |
| Score < 0                     | 98231  |
| Score > 0                     | 2132   |
| At least 1 Answer on Question | 20057  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
```

Of these users **13673** hit a question or answer block.  **50174** users went on to ask another question or post an answer:

```
+------------------------+--------+
|                        | Users  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Asked Another Question | 44611  |
| Answered               | 17443  |
| Post Scored > 0        | 17426  |
| Post Scored < 0        | 28519  |
+------------------------+--------+
```

The numbers of the users who have recently logged into the site:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Days Since Active | Total Users |
+-------------------+-------------+
| < 7               |      24419  |
| 7 - 30            |      14584  |
| 30 - 60           |      12628  |
| 60 - 90           |      10074  |
| 90 - 120          |       7942  |
| 120 - 180         |      19262  |
| 180+              |      35983  |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

### Users with First Question Scored > 0

Here are the stats for the **112641** users who had their first question receive a score > 0. Of these questions:

```
+-------------------------------+--------+
|        Question Stats         | Total  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Closed                        |  3375  |
| Deleted                       |  2132  |
| At least 1 Answer on Question | 87135  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
```

**2831** users hit a question or answer block. **59728** users went on to participate by posting again:

```
+------------------------+--------+
|                        | Users  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Asked Another Question | 47756  |
| Answered               | 31787  |
| Post Scored > 0        | 31190  |
| Post Scored < 0        | 23792  |
+------------------------+--------+
```

The numbers of the users who have recently logged into the site:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Days Since Active | Total Users |
+-------------------+-------------+
| < 7               |      35410  |
| 7 - 30            |      13869  |
| 30 - 60           |       9890  |
| 60 - 90           |       7557  |
| 90 - 120          |       5751  |
| 120 - 180         |      14611  |
| 180+              |      25553  |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

### Users with First Question Score > 0 and Closed

There were **3375** users who had their first question score > 0, but the question was still closed.

```
+-------------------------------+--------+
|        Question Stats         | Total  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Deleted                       |  201   |
| At least 1 Answer on Question | 2550   |
+-------------------------------+--------+
```

Of these users **145** hit a question or answer block. **1817** users posted again:

```
+------------------------+--------+
|                        | Users  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Asked Another Question | 1586   |
| Answered               |  809   |
| Post Scored > 0        |  959   |
| Post Scored < 0        |  907   |
+------------------------+--------+
```

The numbers of the users who have recently logged into the site:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Days Since Active | Total Users |
+-------------------+-------------+
| < 7               |      1088   |
| 7 - 30            |       471   |
| 30 - 60           |       309   |
| 60 - 90           |       249   |
| 90 - 120          |       203   |
| 120 - 180         |       429   |
| 180+              |       626   |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

### Users with First Question Score > 0 and Deleted

There were **2132** users who had their first question score > 0, but the question was deleted.

```
+-------------------------------+--------+
|        Question Stats         | Total  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Closed                        |  201   |
| At least 1 Answer on Question |  553   |
+-------------------------------+--------+
```

**82** users hit a question or answer block, but **1166** users posted again:

```
+------------------------+--------+
|                        | Users  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Asked Another Question | 1052   |
| Answered               |  474   |
| Post Scored > 0        |  616   |
| Post Scored < 0        |  498   |
+------------------------+--------+
```

The numbers of the users who have recently logged into the site:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Days Since Active | Total Users |
+-------------------+-------------+
| < 7               |       608   |
| 7 - 30            |       252   |
| 30 - 60           |       183   |
| 60 - 90           |       174   |
| 90 - 120          |       104   |
| 120 - 180         |       300   |
| 180+              |       511   |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

### Users with First Question Scored < 0

For comparison, breaking down the details on the **150112** users who had their first question receive a score < 0.

```
+-------------------------------+--------+
|        Question Stats         | Total  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Closed                        |  55926 |
| Deleted                       |  98231 |
| At least 1 Answer on Question |  60382 |
+-------------------------------+--------+
```

**19428** of these users hit a question or answer block.  Even though their first question wasn't scored over 0, **62348** users asked another question or posted an answer, of which:

```
+------------------------+--------+
|                        | Users  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Asked Another Question |  54326 |
| Answered               |  22625 |
| Post Scored > 0        |  19731 |
| Post Scored < 0        |  35611 |
+------------------------+--------+
```

How many of these users were still active on the site:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Days Since Active | Total Users |
+-------------------+-------------+
| < 7               |       32751 |
| 7 - 30            |       18868 |
| 30 - 60           |       14816 |
| 60 - 90           |       11550 |
| 90 - 120          |        9059 |
| 120 - 180         |       21882 |
| 180+              |       41179 |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

### Users with First Question Score < 0 and Closed

There were **55926** users who had their first question score < 0 and it was closed.

```
+-------------------------------+--------+
|        Question Stats         | Total  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Deleted                       |  46668 |
| At least 1 Answer on Question |  18271 |
+-------------------------------+--------+
```

Of these users, **8493** hit a question or answer block.  **22453** users posted another question or answer:

```
+------------------------+--------+
|                        | Users  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Asked Another Question | 20146  |
| Answered               |  7076  |
| Post Scored > 0        |  6578  |
| Post Scored < 0        | 13967  |
+------------------------+--------+
```

The numbers of the users who have recently logged into the site:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Days Since Active | Total Users |
+-------------------+-------------+
| < 7               |       12089 |
| 7 - 30            |        7749 |
| 30 - 60           |        5845 |
| 60 - 90           |        4615 |
| 90 - 120          |        3673 |
| 120 - 180         |        8003 |
| 180+              |       13952 |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

### Users with First Question Score < 0 and Deleted

There were **98231** users who had their first question score < 0 and the question was also deleted.

```
+-------------------------------+--------+
|        Question Stats         | Total  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Closed                        |  46668 |
| At least 1 Answer on Question |  14761 |
+-------------------------------+--------+
```

**12265** users hit a block, but **37513** users posted again

```
+------------------------+--------+
|                        | Users  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Asked Another Question |  33301 |
| Answered               |  12586 |
| Post Scored > 0        |  11762 |
| Post Scored < 0        |  22108 |
+------------------------+--------+
```

Finally, the numbers of the users who have recently been active:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Days Since Active | Total Users |
+-------------------+-------------+
| < 7               |       17535 |
| 7 - 30            |       11138 |
| 30 - 60           |       10032 |
| 60 - 90           |        8073 |
| 90 - 120          |        6388 |
| 120 - 180         |       15472 |
| 180+              |       29593 |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

### Conclusions

23% of new users received a positive score on their first question, and 53% of them went on to ask or answer another question. 27% of the users continued to post content that received a score > 0.

There were 31% of users whose first question received a score less than zero. Of these users 41% continued to participate on the site, by asking another question or answering, but only 13% of their posts received a score > 0.

About 2% of new users who got a score > 0 on their first question hit a block in the past year, while 13% of the users with a score < 0 hit either a question or answer block.

Users who have a well-received first question may have put a bit more effort into the post, which resulted in a positive score. That being said, if your first question isn't scored > 0, it doesn't preclude the user from learning how to ask a better question and finding success on the site.

Comment: "if your first question is well-received you're likely to perform better long term" hmm, doesn't this mean that someone who puts in effort on their first attempt is likely to also put in effort on subsequent attempts? I'm not seeing an epiphany there.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Yes, that's correct there is no epiphany here it repeats a lot of things said over time. if a user spends time writing their first question and it gets upvoted, more than likely they will put the same effort in subsequent posts. Users who don't put effort into their questions, probably won't have much success.

Comment: @JeffAtwood, did you not see the *correlation*?  If that doesn't tell you there's *causation*, I don't know what will.  :P  bluefeet,To Jeff's point, it's probably worth calling out the detail behind your last sentence:  "Now, It's not clear how much of that is a function of the first-post-experience, vs. a posters innate likelihood to be adept at asking good questions, putting in more effort, etc"

Comment: @jaydles I feel the "ask question" page is the single least changed page on Stack since 2008 and it is wildly overdue for a serious overhaul to help first time askers.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what does `hit either a question or answer block` mean? What's a question block or answer block?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce We have things in place to warn users or block users who consistently post bad content. Here are a few discussions about the q-block http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236568/breaking-down-question-blocks-lets-talk-about-rate-limits and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th, similar things can happen to answers.

Comment: Lots of these tables contain rows for `Post Scored > 0` and `Post Scored < 0`. What about `Post Scored = 0`?

Comment: Just to note: 1) Some *terrible* questions are upvoted (for reasons unbeknownst to me), and some great questions are never seen or voted on. 2) Some first time users ask terrible first questions, but learn from the mistakes they've made and learn to post great questions. 3) Some ask great first questions, and then perhaps get cocky and don't bother to keep their discipline on subsequent questions. 4) Some new users never ask questions, but only provide answers. Some of those users provide bad answers, some provide excellent answers. Some old users have never asked a question.

Comment: Some "new" users may be old users who have iffy questions that they don't want to post under their normal accounts, because...

Comment: @JeffAtwood, agree. I've long wanted to offer a "guided" ask that's the default for new askers, with more of a wizard-style guide with separate fields for "code" what "what you want to happen," "what is happening", "details about the version, system, etc.," I think we could easily help users NOT crash into most of the fixable mistakes that get made.   It's been on the "definitely worth doing... Soon" list too long, but I'll push to get this locked in on a "this year for realz" roadmap.

Comment: @Jaydles strong +1 on that. There are so many things that could be done to help new users have a positive early experience. The most trivial thing: check to see that the question includes code! A new question template with boilerplate language that they can overwrite would also provide guidance. Plus a quick check for similar questions to avoid dupes.

Comment: By the way, I've accepted this answer as it provides a lot of very rich information that can be used as the basis for further analysis. Thank you everyone for the rich and polite discussion on the topic and all the info. This was my first question on meta and it went better than expected ;)

Comment: @Jaydles It needs to work with each sites' needs. Many sites aren't about debugging.